# Using fmincon in a way that the results are taken out of a vector which is set by myself

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, vector

Is it possible to use fmincon so that the result is not a continuous x in a range `lower_bound <= x <= upper_bound`, but concrete numbers that I specify.

In my case, the matrix E is to be determined. Numbers in a vector such as `V = [0.3 0.5 1]` are to be distributed in the matrix E in such a way that another result C calculated with E becomes minimal.

An examples of possible result would be:

```
E = [ 0.3 0.3 0.5 1;
      0.5 0.5 0.3 0.5;
      1   0.3 0.3 0.5]
```

Comment: If your test set is that small, can you not just test all values and pick the minimum? Otherwise this looks like more of an [integer programming](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/integer-programming.html) problem. Your question could be improved with a [mcve]

Comment: @Wolfie In fact, E is a very large matrix, e.g. 100x100x100. If one would want to solve the task by permutation, one would have extremely long computation times, since the computation of C is very complex. A mini example would be very good, but I could not build it, because I did not know how to apply fmincon in my case. The article on integer programming problem seems very promising, thanks for that. I'll have to read into that.

Comment: A minimal example might include inputs and the expected outputs, along with how you'd expect to arrive at those outputs - not necessarily something which actually works but something which could be used to validate a proposed solution